# How to compare strings in date format in Objective C

Tags: ios, objective-c, nsdateformatter

I have two strings with the format as Fri, 22 Jan 2016 10:46:50 +0530. I need to compare these two strings.If it can be done by converting them to date ,how can i write that NSDateFormatter style. Tried the code below. but not working. I'm getting the newDate and  currentDate as nil. Any help would be appreciated.

```
NSString *dateString1 = @"Fri, 22 Jan 2016 10:46:50 +0530";
NSString *dateString2 = @"Fri, 21 Jan 2016 10:46:50 +0530";
NSDateFormatter *inputFormatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
[inputFormatter setDateStyle:NSDateFormatterFullStyle];

NSDate *newDate = [inputFormatter dateFromString:dateString1];
NSDate *currentDate = [inputFormatter dateFromString:dateString2];

[inputFormatter release];

NSComparisonResult result = [newDate compare:currentDate]; // comparing two dates

if(result == NSOrderedAscending || result == NSOrderedSame) {
    NSLog(@"newDate is less or same");
}
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Use `[inputFormatter setDateFormat:@"EEE, DD MMM yyyy HH:mm:ss z"];`

```
    NSString *dateString1 = @"Fri, 22 Jan 2016 10:46:50 +0530";
    NSString *dateString2 = @"Fri, 22 Jan 2016 10:46:50 +0530";

    NSDateFormatter *inputFormatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];

    [inputFormatter setDateFormat:@"EEE, dd MMM yyyy HH:mm:ss Z"];

    NSDate *newDate = [inputFormatter dateFromString:dateString1];
    NSDate *currentDate = [inputFormatter dateFromString:dateString2];

    NSComparisonResult result = [newDate compare:currentDate]; // comparing two dates

    if(result == NSOrderedAscending || result == NSOrderedSame) {
        NSLog(@"newDate is less or same");
    }
```

Answer (score 3):

set dateformat like

if your time format is 12 hour - use `hh` else if your time format is 24 hour use - `HH`

```
      NSString *dateString1 = @"Fri, 22 Jan 2016 10:46:50 +0530";
[inputFormatter setDateFormat:@"EEE, dd MMM yyyy HH:mm:ss Z"];
```

if you are using ARC no need of this `[inputFormatter release];`

Comment: try and tell what the answer you get finally